# Runtime of a while loop that grows exponentially

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I am trying to find the runtime of the following code in terms of $n$:

```
i = 2;
while (i < n) {
  i = i * i * i;
}
```

I understand if the increment was just $i = i \cdot i$ the runtime would be $\lceil \log \log n\rceil$ of base $2$, but I have no idea what $i\cdot i\cdot i$ would be like, I don't think $\lceil \log \log \log n\rceil$ works because substituting  $n = 3$ would give us $0$, which is not correct.

Comment: Let n = 2^k and determine the runtime in terms of k.

Comment: could you clarify? Im not too good with proofs so I dont really know how to derive this even with n = 2^k

Comment: Notice that $i$ will always be a number of the form $2^k$, starting with $k=1$. What does the loop body do to $k$?